# Declaring a new variable inside Object

Tags: javascript

I've been playing with JS and I'm trying to assign a new variable inside an object method but I keep getting hit with undefined in the console.

This is the object I created:

```
const rodrigo = {
    firstName: 'Rodrigo',
    lastName: 'Pinto',
    job: 'Programmer',
    birthYEar: '1997',
    friends: ['Michael', 'Scott', 'Jim'],
    hasDriversLicense: true,

    calcAge: function () {
        this.age = 2021 - this.birthYEar;
        return this.age; //We don't actually need to return anything here actually, because we already said that age = calculation.
    }
```

But when I try to log rodrigo.age it returns undefined.
Could someone walk me through this? I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `this` is the global object

Comment: You never call `calcAge`? How/where do you call it?

Comment: because you did not call the calcAge function when you will call the method it will have the age key available in object

Comment: You may want to consider changing the `calcAge` method into a [property getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). Then you would simply call `rodrigo.age` and it would run the logic in `calcAge` and return the calculated age. I also suggest storing `birthYEar` as a) `birthYear` and b) a number value (i.e., `birthYear: 1997,`), then use `new Date().getFullYear()` instead of hard-coding 2021. I might be jumping ahead of the curriculum though (sorry, teachers always hated me for that... :)).

Answer (score 2):

Your object doesn't initially have an `age` property assigned to it. To be able to access `age` you need to execute the `calcAge` function via `rodrigo.calcAge()` first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `rodrigo.age` to return something, you'll have to define that property. But since you defined `calcAge` instead, and never call that method, there is no `age` property (yet).

One solution is to replace `calcAge` with a getter function named `age`. The advantage is then that you can read `rogrigo.age` and implicitly invoke that function:

```js
const rodrigo = {
    firstName: 'Rodrigo',
    lastName: 'Pinto',
    job: 'Programmer',
    birthYear: '1997',
    friends: ['Michael', 'Scott', 'Jim'],
    hasDriversLicense: true,

    get age() {
        return new Date().getFullYear() - this.birthYear;
    }
}

console.log(rodrigo.age);
```

Side note: the calculation of age is a bit more complex than this -- you need to know someone's full birthdate and compare it with the current month and date to see whether it already passed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rodrigo = {
    firstName: 'Rodrigo',
    lastName: 'Pinto',
    job: 'Programmer',
    birthYEar: '1997',
    friends: ['Michael', 'Scott', 'Jim'],
    hasDriversLicense: true,

    calcAge: function () {
        this.age = 2021 - this.birthYEar;
        console.log(this.age);
        return this.age;
    }
  }
  
  rodrigo.calcAge();
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there are different ways to define a user-defined object types. In your case I will recommend to use a constructor function. So just follow the idea of the snippet below.

```js
function Rodrigo() {
    this.firstName = 'Rodrigo';
    this.lastName = 'Pinto';
    this.job = 'Programmer';
    this.birthYEar = '1997';
    this.friends = ['Michael', 'Scott', 'Jim'];
    this.hasDriversLicense = true;
    this.calcAge = function () {
        this.age = 2021 - this.birthYEar;
        return this.age;
    };
    this.calcAge();
}

console.log((new Rodrigo()).age);
```